# Debugging user-defined function

Tags: r

For a dataset of "[Baltimore homicides](http://data.baltimoresun.com/homicides/)"
It is required to create a function that takes a string for example **"shooting"** and return an integer represents the count of victims of "shooting".
I wrote the following function but i receive errors

> Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
>
> Error: object 'counti' not found

I also cant figure out if the **==Null** is correct

```
count <- function(cause = NULL) {

## Check that "cause" is non-NULL; else throw error
if cause==NULL
{
stop()
print("no cause provided")
}

## Read "homicides.txt" data file
homicides <- readLines("homicides.txt")
## Extract causes of death
i <- grep(cause, homicides)  ##get indices of cause
counti <- lenghth(i) ##get count of indices
## Check that specific "cause" is allowed; else throw error
if counti=0
{
stop()
print("no such cause")
}

## Return integer containing count of homicides for that cause      
return(counti)  
}
```

---

this is my working function after edit, thanks guys

```
count <- function(cause = NULL) {
  if(missing(cause) | is.null(cause)) stop("no cause provided")
  homicides <- readLines("homicides.txt")
  i=length(grep(cause, homicides))
  if(i==0) stop("no cause found")
  return(i)
  }
```

Comment: At a minimum, you're missing parenthesis around if statements and you're using `==` instead of `is.null`.

Comment: @GSee, thanks. I will edit my question accordingly. Is there a reason for not "finding" counti

Comment: Also, `stop()` means exactly that. It will never get to the next `print()`.

Comment: And you've misspelt `length()`

Comment: and your last `if` uses `=` instead of `==` (in addition to not using parenthesis)

Comment: @Andrie and GSee thanks a lot Guys. I will edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your function to 2 lines by doing this:

```
count <- function(cause = NULL, data) {
  if(is.null(cause)) stop("no cause provided")
  length(grep(cause, data))
}

data <- c("murder", "some other cause")

count("murder", data)
[1] 1
```

Note the following principles:

- R has many features of a functional language. This means that each function should, as far as possible, depend only on the arguments you pass it.
- When you have a bug in your code, simplify it to the shortest possible version, fix the bug, then build out from there.

Also, keep `stop()` for really fatal errors.  Not finding a search string in your data isn't an error, it simply means the cause wasn't found.  You don't want your code to stop.  At most, issue a `message()` or a `warning()`.

Comment: Should be `||` not `|`, and `missing()` is basically redundant since `NULL` is the default

Comment: @hadley Good point. I edited the post to reflect your sage advice.